# test folder configuration in web project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I have a spring web project in eclipse which has folder structure as

```
src/main/java 
src/main/resources
src/test/java
src/test/resources
```

For some time my eclipse project used to work fine. But recently, when i start the application my eclipse project loads spring annotated beans from

```
src/test/java
```

folder.Because of this i am getting

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
```

from spring as there are two implementations of the same spring bean.

When i remove this folder from build path my application works well. Can someone please help with the reason for such behavioral change in my project?

Answer (score 0):

we have two types of ioc containers in spring BeanFactory,ApplicationContext.when a request comes bean factory creates the instance which we declare a bean in xml. but application context creates all bean instances at the time of loading....